# What's wrong with this ASP connection string?

Tags: asp-classic, connection-string, adoconnection

I'm at the end of my rope on this.  It should be so simple.
I just need to know what's wrong with this connection string:

```
dbc.open ("Driver={SQL Server}; Data Source = ServerName; Initial Catalog = InitialDB; " "User ID = Username; Password = Password;")
```

I get this error when running that line:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I know ServerName is up and accepting connections, I know InitialDB exists, I know User ID and Password are valid for the database.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is DBC? it looks more like you are pushing a bizzarely split connection string into the command text and connection arguments of the record sets open method.. where as you need to set the ConnectionString property of the ado connection.

Comment: Apologies; the split is because in the code it's got a & _ construct to make it more readable and I forgot to edit it out fully. 

Dbc's declaration: Set dbc = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
dbc.open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Driver={SQL Server}; Data Source = ServerName; Initial Catalog = InitialDB; User ID = Username; Password = Password; Network Library=dbmssocn;")
```

Comment: @TTT : Are you using an ADODB.connection?  What version of SQL Server are you using?  Are either Named Pipes or TCP connections disabled?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment - I must have screwed something up before.  I deleted the entire string and typed it back in using your code block as a guide and it seems to be working now.

Making too many mistakes today, I need a nap!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

In notepad create file anyname.udl - let it be empty. After in explorer click it - you will get a dialog to create OLEDB connection string, select expected driver, and all connection param, ensure that "Allow saving password" = True. Press Ok.
Then again open file with notepad. Content is valid connection string

Comment: FWIW, this technique omitted the Provider property and thus did not work.

Comment: Look at "Advanced"/"All" tab and press Edit value - there are extended properties for provider.

Answer (score 1):

As someone has already pointed out, udl is the best easiest way to create a conn string - here is a link that talks about it. https://web.archive.org/web/20210211044624/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070400-1.shtml

Comment: That would have been great to know about 6 years ago! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ADOdb you might want to try

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD"
```

for SQL Server 2008 Native Client or

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD"
```

for SQL Server 2005 Native Client.

For ODBC, use

```
"Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0"
```

for SQL Server 2008 Native Client or

```
"Driver=SQL Native Client"
```

for SQL Server 2005 Native Client.

Answer (score 0):

What's with the " " in the middle of the string?

Comment: Apologies; in my editor I used a & _ extention that I forgot to edit out fully when I posted the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string appears to be mixing ODBC and OLEDB.  I would suggest visiting http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and finding the correct syntax for the desired provider.

***Yours***:

```
"Driver={SQL Server}; Data Source = ServerName; Initial Catalog = InitialDB; " "User ID = Username; Password = Password;"
```

***ODBC***:

```
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerName;Database=InitialDB;Uid=Username;Pwd=Password;"
```

***OLEDB***:

```
"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=InitialDB;User Id=Username;Password=Password;"
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have visual studio?

Connect to the database server, and locate the database you want to connect to.

Right click, select properties.  Your connection string to the db is right there.
Copy to wherever you want. -- Should be in web config, but you can paste it directly into code if you so desire.